# How to stop a 'complex' macro (could not solve this with existing topics)

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a code of the following structure:

- UserForm1 with some fields and start button
- When the start button is clicked, a function starts running and after a while it triggers another function inside itself (retrieveing some data from web, using DoEvents a lot during loading web pages and looping through data). Also, another UserForm2 appears.
- The UserForm2 contains the code execution status and a button to stop the execution and exit all functions.

The problem is that I cannot have the UserForm2 react to user input (cannot click the stop button to set "isCancelled" global varibale to True) no matter what I try. Maybe it does not react because the code is running not from the UserForm2 but fom the UserForm1 and another module functions? (I am absolutely not an expert in coding).

So what I need is simple: stop cycles scraping data, close both UserForms and exit sub.

Comment: Unload formName and Exit Sub

Comment: How to unload it? The code does not react to clicks (cannot click any button). And exit sub from the functions does not work.

Comment: You can't start running a new macro by clicking on a button when Excel is already running another. You could use the `Pause|Break` button to stop the code manually

Comment: Change UserForms `ShowModal` to `False`. Add `DoEvents` statements into loops and in other places along the code. Use simple `End` command withing a button event, whenever you want to terminate code execution.

Comment: @omegastripes I did - the button still can't be clicked (no reaction). I added "form.show vbmodeless" to both forms and also added "DoEvents" in every loop and other places.